# Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions' did not migrate i'm making crm and i

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm making this crm and i got this error i will share code with you

i'm taking this video and i got this error

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOukA4Qh9QA&t=4925s

```
ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
leads.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.
leads.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
```

Setting.py

Here's my settings code
"""

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'leads',


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODELS = 'leads.User'
```

models.py

Here's my models code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Lead(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    agent = models.ForeignKey("Agent",on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Agent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: i can't immediately see the problem, but i would suggest that if you don't need to add the User subclass to the AbstractUser class, so... removing the User class and removing the AUTH_USER_MODELS could fix your issue, use these "from django.contrib.auth.models import User" to bring the default User model into these Scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting is named [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL), not `AUTH_USER_MODELS` since you can specify *exactly one* model not multiple ones:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'leads.User'
```

Comment: Bro when type this then i got this error ERRORS:
leads.User.user_ptr: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

Comment: @DeveloperLachi: are you sure you did not inherit from `User` instead of `AbstactUser`?

Comment: class User(User,AbstractUser):
    pass

Comment: from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser

Comment: @DeveloperLachi: remove the `User,` part, you can no longer subclass from `User`, since that would mean there are two user models active.

Comment: when i remove that i got this You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'agent' to lead without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:

Comment: @DeveloperLachi: well apparently your database already has an `Agent` model that now refers to the new `User` object. If possible, I would remove all the migrations for this app, and clear the database, and start construction of the tables thus from scratch.